Termux: am command - start intent without activity class
I'm trying to launch an intent to a shortcut of a flow on Automate (by Llamalabs) using the am command supplied by Termux, but the am command needs the Activity Class parameter to run the shortcut and I can't find it. Automate was able to run it fine without an activity class, but I just can't figure out how to do it with the am command.
How can I accomplish running a intent without an Activity class on the am command?
I did try running commands like this:
am start -a com.llamalab.automate.intent.action.START_FLOW -d content://com.llamalab.automate.provider/flows/58/statements/ -c android.intent.category.DEFAULT
But it resulted in this output
Starting: Intent { act=com.llamalab.automate.intent.action.START_FLOW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=content://com.llamalab.automate.provider/... }

Error: Activity not started, unable to resolve Intent { act=com.llamalab.automate.intent.action.START_FLOW cat=[android.intent.category.DEFAULT] dat=content://com.llamalab.automate.provider/... flg=0x10000000 }

And I tried researching more on the am command, but still with no luck. I did find the monkey command built into the Android shell, but that doesn't work as it keeps saying that the window manager isn't running.
Parameters I have on the shortcut for the intent:
Data URI: content://com.llamalab.automate.provider/flows/58/statements/1

Action: com.llamalab.automate.intent.action.START_FLOW

Package: com.llamalab.automate


According to the developer, try am broadcast -a com.llamalab.automate.intent.action.START_FLOW -d $dataURI -n com.llamalab.automate/.StartServiceReceiver ? It will send an intent broadcast instead of starting an activity.

That worked. Guess I just missed it while researching. Thanks!

@AndrewT. found that you actually needed to broadcast rather than attempting to start an app activity.
am broadcast -a com.llamalab.automate.intent.action.START_FLOW -d $dataURI -n com.llamalab.automate/.StartServiceReceiver
